# How to set Tcl/Tk "system configuration" items?

Tags: macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/tk_mac.htm#M20 talks about a "System configuration parameter", which is supposed to modify toplevel background on Mac.

How should I set this parameter in Tkinter?

I tried `tk_root.option_add("::tk::mac::useThemedToplevel", 1)` but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that was for MacOS, last released in 1999.
When using the 'aqua' theme on Mac OS X, the theme colors can't be changed.

If you need to have a changeable color, use the older widgets, 'frame', 'label', etc.
(I have no idea if that's possible in tkinter).

Comment: I wanted to avoid the situation where toplevel background doesn't match with widgets' (eg. `ttk.Label`) background. Seems that the most robust solution is to host all widgets on a `ttk.Frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

> configuring the toplevel with “-background systemWindowHeaderBackground”

according to the link info?.

I'm a tcl'er so i can't help with that using tkinter. If doesn't works, you could take a look to these other links:

[MacWindowStyle](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13428) : a MacOS X command to create toplevel windows with a variety of appearances

[Tk differences on Mac OS X](http://wiki.tcl.tk/44444): include some bugs.

(Or can search for more info about Mac in the tcl/tk wiki.)

I hope this help you,

Saludos!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I chose using a `ttk.Frame` which covers whole toplevel and hosts all widgets.