# How to make Tkinter look good or natural on mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I developed a simple application using Tkinter, python 3.7.4 and on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6.
I executed the same code on Ubuntu 18.04 and the latest Windows 10, and the application looks native. However, when I run it on my Macbook, it doesn't look native, like other mac GUI apps.

Look at this screenshot for instance:
[image]

Notice the gray backgrounds on widgets.

Here's the code for this:

```
import datetime
import gettext
import sys
import time
import os
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

# All translations provided for illustrative purposes only.
# english
_ = lambda s: s


class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    "Main area of user interface content."

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        paddings = {'padx': 6, 'pady': 6}
        self.download_location = '/'.join(os.getcwd().split('/')[:3]) + '/Downloads'
        ttk.Label(parent, text="Youtube Url").pack(side='top', anchor='w', **paddings)
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(parent, )
        self.entry.pack(side='top', fill='x', **paddings)

        # todo delete this line
        self.entry.insert(0, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXait2wHOQc')

        self.button = ttk.Button(parent, text="Download", command=self.do_download)
        self.button.pack(side='top', **paddings, anchor='w')

        # style = ttk.Style()
        # style.configure('TButton', foreground="red")
        # self.button.config(style='Alarm.TButton')

        self.location_button = ttk.Button(parent, text="Location", command=self.browse_button)
        self.location_button.pack(side='top', **paddings, anchor='w')

        self.statusStringVar = StringVar()
        self.statusStringVar.set('status here')
        self.status = ttk.Label(parent, textvariable=self.statusStringVar, text='status', )
        self.status.pack(side='top', anchor='w', fill='x', **paddings)

        self.locStringVar = StringVar()
        self.locStringVar.set(f"Location: {self.download_location}")
        self.locationLabel = ttk.Label(parent, textvariable=self.locStringVar, )
        self.locationLabel.pack(side='top', anchor='w', fill='x', **paddings)

        self.mp3_check_value = StringVar()
        self.mp3_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(parent, text='Convert to MP3')
        self.mp3_checkbox.config(variable=self.mp3_check_value, onvalue='yes', offvalue='no')
        self.mp3_check_value.set('yes')
        self.mp3_checkbox.pack(side='top', anchor='w', **paddings)

        self.progressIntVar = IntVar()
        self.progressIntVar.set(0)
        self.mpb = ttk.Progressbar(parent, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate")
        self.mpb['variable'] = self.progressIntVar
        self.mpb.pack(side='top', anchor='w', fill='x', **paddings)
        self.mpb["maximum"] = 100
        # self.mpb["value"] = 0

    def do_download(self):
        pass

    def progress_hook(self, d):
        pass

    def browse_button(self):
        filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
        print(filename)
        self.download_location = filename
        self.locStringVar.set(f"Location: {self.download_location}")


class Application(tkinter.Tk):
    "Create top-level Tkinter widget containing all other widgets."

    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.wm_title('Tkinter YDL')
        self.wm_geometry('640x480')

        self.mainframe = MainFrame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(side='right', fill='y')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    APPLICATION_GUI = Application()
    APPLICATION_GUI.mainloop()
```

Am I missing something here? Please help.

Comment: `ttk` widgets are "themed", so you may be able to make them look more native on MacOS by creating a custom theme. Here's a little (somewhat-dated but still applicable)  [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190315202103id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk.html) about them.

Comment: Relevant [how-to-set-tcl-tk-system-configuration-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464078/how-to-set-tcl-tk-system-configuration-items/52465157#52465157)

Comment: Don't all of those widgets look native already though?

Comment: Maybe I just need to change the Frame's background to macs color.

Comment: @osama7901: If you find a solution, please post it as an answer here to your own question — which is allowed — for others to use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you put the label into the parent window, and not into the ttk frame. This is why the background color is different. You should set `self`as the parent for the label.

```py
ttk.Label(self, text="Youtube Url").pack(side='top', anchor='w', **paddings)
```

Answer (score -1):

I just saw this theme posted on reddit:

https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme

It's based on a Microsoft visual style but it definitely looks better than the default ttk theme.

Also scroll to the bottom for two other themes by the same author.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually change the background color of the tk or ttk labels to white, if the os is mac. To learn about that check [How to identify on which OS Python is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/how-to-identify-on-which-os-python-is-running-on) (that is if you don't know)

[You can see on windows it looks properly native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvLiy.png)

Or you could try setting the theme to "aqua" which only works on mac

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).